# Exporting maya file in stl

Tags: python, animation, maya, mel

I have been saving files as .stl in Maya OSX 2015 for a while for 3D printing, but recently, Maya stopped recognizing .stl at all for import or export.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming Q&A site, hence as your question is unrelated to programming, it is very unlikely that you will get an answer here and your question will probably gets closed. I'd recommend you to post directly on Autodesk forums or Creative Crash for example. Maybe folks on [Gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) could help you with this.

Comment: Concerning your question, have you checked your plugin manager? Be sure that `DirectConnect.mll` is loaded it seems that this is the plugin that enable the .stl import/export.

Answer (score 0):

For having an opportunity to export your Maya's geometry as `STL_DCE` file format you need to activate `DirectConnect.bundle`.

Go to `Windows` –> `Settings/Preferences` –> `Plug-in Manager` and under `../Maya.app/Contents/MacOS/plug-ins` section choose `Loaded` and `Auto load` options for DirectConnect.bundle.

There is also MEL command you must enter directly in Script Editor:

```
// MEL command for loading DirectConnect.bundle
loadPlugin DirectConnect;

// MEL command for loading all Maya's plug-ins
loadPlugin -allPlugins;
```

As well as Python command:

```
# Python equivalent for loading DirectConnect.bundle
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.loadPlugin( 'DirectConnect' )

# Python equivalent for loading all Maya's plug-ins
cmds.loadPlugin( allPlugins = True )
```